# Adding elements in arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm facing a problem.

I have two elements as follow :

```
[array([130.05297852, 159.25004578, 140.36545944]),
array([115.27301025, 160.63392258, 132.83247375])]
```

and

```
[39.44091796875,
52.175140380859375]
```

and I would like to have something like that :

```
[array([130.05297852, 159.25004578, 140.36545944, 39.44091796875]),
array([115.27301025, 160.63392258, 132.83247375, 52.175140380859375])]
```

How can I manage to do this ? Thanks !

Comment: Are those NumPy arrays?

Comment: You may want to precise what libraries you are using and what you have tried to get the desired results. This will help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
a = [
    np.array([130.05297852, 159.25004578, 140.36545944]),
    np.array([115.27301025, 160.63392258, 132.83247375])
]
add_to_a = np.array([39.44091796875, 52.175140380859375])
result = []
for i, j in zip(a, add_to_a):
    final = np.append(i, j)
    result.append(final)

print(result)  # If you need a normal array
result = np.array(result)  # Making ND Array
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks ! But I'm losing the fact that I want a nd array. Actually I would like then to create a csv and a column for each column in the list, before I used : **import csv
example_list = final
with open('example.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in example_list:
        writer.writerow(line)**

Comment: i just edited the comment :) 
hope the final `result` is what you want.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks you so much for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can append elements with the append function.

```
for i in range(len(small_array)):
    bigger_array[i].append(small_array[i])
```

this appends the first element to the first array, and the second element to the second array.

EDIT:

with numpy arrays you can adapt the previous method in this way:

```
for i in range(len(small_array):
    np.append(bigger_array[i], small_array[i])
```